# AttributeError: 'spacy.tokens.doc.Doc' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, tokenize, spacy, doc

I am working on appending texts in a list, and then change the texts to be word embeddings and then do machine learning. The 'insts' in 'articles' is collected by using spacy, but then I am faced with this error as follows, can someone please tell me how to fix this error? Can I change the type ''spacy.tokens.doc.Doc' into 'str'?

```py
def main(annotations_file, max_insts=-1):
    articles = reader.read_corpus(annotations_file,max_insts=max_insts)
    texts=[]
    random.seed(5)
    random.shuffle(articles)
    # arti = list()
    sect = list()
    label_bef=list()
    label_dur=list()
    label_aft=list()

    for insts in articles:
        for inst in insts:
            texts.append(inst.possessor.doc._.article_title_doc)
            #sect.append(inst.possessor.doc._.section_title_doc)
            label_bef.append(inst.labels['BEF'])
            label_dur.append(inst.labels['DUR'])
            label_aft.append(inst.labels['AFT'])

    embeddings_index = {}
    with open('glove.6B.100d.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            word, coefs = line.split(maxsplit=1)
            coefs = np.fromstring(coefs, 'f', sep=' ')
            embeddings_index[word] = coefs

    tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=MAX_NUM_WORDS)
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(texts)
    word_index = tokenizer.word_index
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "sample.py", line 117, in <module>
     main(args.ANNOTATIONS_FILE, args.max_articles)
   File "sample.py", line 51, in main
     tokenizer.fit_on_texts(texts)
   File "/home/huweilong/miniconda3/envs/nre/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/text.py", line 223, in fit_on_texts
self.split)
   File "/home/huweilong/miniconda3/envs/nre/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/text.py", line 43, in text_to_word_sequence
     text = text.lower()
   AttributeError: 'spacy.tokens.doc.Doc' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: Just do `doc.lower_`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the string representation of a spaCy document by calling `doc.text`.